# Filters for TreeStoreBuilder

Tags: rally

I'm just getting started try to code scripts for Rally that can be utilized for a confluence wiki. I've gotten the basic TreeStoreBuilder to work with my number of fields, but I need to constrain it to an  iteration (ideally latest) as well as hard code project/subproject as that I'm expecting would need to be constrained as I want to have multiple charts from different projects on 1 wiki page. The code that I have so far is below..

Thanks!
Mark

```
enter code here
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
     models: ['userstory'],
      autoLoad: true,
      enableHierarchy: true
  }).then({
      success: function(store) {
         Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                items: [{
                 xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                 columnCfgs: [
                     'DisplayColor',
                     'Name',
                     'ScheduleState',
                     'Blocked',
                     'TaskEstimateTotal',
                     'TaskRemainingTotal',
                     'Owner',
                     'Notes'
                 ],
                 store: store
             }],
             renderTo: Ext.getBody()
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: I was able to add some filtering and was able to get things to work for Iteration.Name and Project.Name... Parent.Name is not working so not sure what I missed there. I'm testing this on my Rally Dashboard and was expecting to be able to generate grids independent on what project I was in. That did not work and had to go to the parent level. Ideally I'm trying to do this via a wiki and will use my API key (read-only) to be the path in... I'm missing something on the context to get the filtering to the right level.. My workspace is abc with multiple projects and subs underneath. Code below

Comment: Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
     models: ['userstory'],
      autoLoad: true,
      enableHierarchy: true,
      filters: [{property: 'Iteration.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'March'},
                {property: 'Parent.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'Synergy'},
                {property: 'Project.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'Condor'}

Answer (score 0):

You can check out filtering here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/data_stores-section-filtering

And project scoping here:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/data_stores-section-scoping

Comment: I was able to add some filtering and was able to get things to work for Iteration.Name and Project.Name... Parent.Name is not working so not sure what I missed there.  I'm testing this on my Rally Dashboard and was expecting to be able to generate grids independent on what project I was in. That did not work and had to go to the parent level.   Ideally I'm trying to do this via a wiki and will use my API key (read-only) to be the path in... I'm missing something on the context to get the filtering to the right level.. My workspace is abc with multiple projects and subs  underneath. Code below

Comment: In Rally you can "pin" an app to a specific project from the Settings menu in the header gear of the app.  Externally you can specify the context with query string params: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/developing_externally-section-controlling-context

As long as you are specifying context when you create your store/grid you should be in good shape...

Comment: Is there a way to do that within the Rally JavaScript? I'm ultimately trying to move this to a confluence wiki for multiple project/subprojects. I'm also trying to get my api key included.. Right now the wiki admin is having me do this via wiki markup so I don't have an iframe path, I have to have it part of the html or rally java code. Thanks! Mark